# How to AWS S3 to Alibaba OSS data sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-oss

Is the below things will be helpful?

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html
2. https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/95159.html?spm=a2c4g.11186623.2.9.dba248faCIdT27#concept-yr2-3cf-qfb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source data to be migrated may be stored in an OSS bucket, a local storage, a third-party cloud storage like AWS S3.

Methods
1. OssImport
- Use the OssImport tool to migrate the data. This tool can migrate historical data of various data sources to OSS in batches.
- https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/56990.htm?spm=a2c63.o282931.879956.5.6a8d43a28Hlgxq

2. OSS APIs/SDKs Copy Object and Upload Part Copy

   - Source data is stored locally: Use OSS APIs/SDKs for code development.
   - If the source data is stored in HTTP or third-party cloud storage, you must write code to download the data from the data source, and then write code, by using OSS APIs/SDKs, 
     to upload the data to OSS.
   - https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/64919.htm?
     spm=a2c63.p38356.a1.1.32ee24420c9vUH